# Groupby and combine a dataframe using Vaex

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

I have a large `.csv` file with roughly 150M rows. I can still fit the entire data set into memory and use Pandas to groupby and combine. Example...

```
aggregated_df = df.groupby(["business_partner", "contract_account"]).sum()
```

In the above example the dataframe contains two integer columns, `business_partner` and `contract_account`, which are used as keys for the grouping operation. The remaining columns can be assumed all be floating point features which I would like to aggregate.

However this only uses 1 of the 48 cores on my workstation. I am trying to use [vaex](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in order to take advantage of all of my cores but cannot figure out the API calls to perform groupby and combine. Perhaps it is not yet possible in Vaex?

Edit(s):

1. I am aware that this operation can be done in dask, but for this question I want to focus on Vaex.

Comment: What does your data look like ?

Comment: @davidrpugh would you perfer to use dask for this operation. It has the same api of that of  pandas (built on top of pandas in way).    `from dask.distributed import Client;
client = Client(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=4, processes=False, memory_limit='2GB') ;df.goupby(["col1", "col2"]).sum().compute()`

Answer (score 8):

You can find a working example in https://docs.vaex.io/en/latest/api.html#vaex.dataframe.DataFrameLocal.groupby

Going with your example of grouping by 2 columns and getting a sum aggregation:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import vaex

# Create input dataframe

n=10**6  # Change this to adjust df size

a_c1 = [1,2,3]*n
a_c2 = [1,1,2,2,3,3]*int(n/2)
a_x = np.arange(float(len(a_c1)))
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':a_c1,'c2':a_c2,'x1':a_x, 'x2':a_x})

# Convert dataframe to vaex

# dfv = vaex.from_pandas(df) # This also works, but it's slower
dfv = vaex.from_arrays(c1=a_c1, c2=a_c2, x1=a_x, x2=a_x)

df_result1 = df.groupby(['c1','c2']).sum()
df_result2 = dfv.groupby(['c1','c2'],agg='sum')
```

The output structure will be slightly different:

```
> print(df_result1)

                 x1            x2
c1 c2                            
1  1   7.499985e+11  7.499985e+11
   2   7.500000e+11  7.500000e+11
2  1   7.499990e+11  7.499990e+11
   3   7.500005e+11  7.500005e+11
3  2   7.499995e+11  7.499995e+11
   3   7.500010e+11  7.500010e+11

> print(df_result2)

  #    c1    c2      x_1_sum      x_2_sum
  0     2     3  7.50000e+11  7.50000e+11
  1     2     1  7.49999e+11  7.49999e+11
  2     3     2  7.5e+11      7.5e+11
  3     3     3  7.50001e+11  7.50001e+11
  4     1     2  7.5e+11      7.5e+11
  5     1     1  7.49998e+11  7.49998e+11
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will have to adjust the limits and number of bins for the grouping manually - but the 'binby' argument should do the job in vaex:

```
df.sum([list of columns you want summed],binby=["business_partner", "contract_account"],limits=['minmax','minmax'],
       shape=[business_partner_bins,contract_account_bins])
```

if you want all columns summed you could replace [list of columns you want summed] by df.column_names

PS. I just noted there is a groupby function in vaex, but I have no experience using it. https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=groupby#vaex.dataframe.DataFrameLocal.groupby

Comment: I will give this a try (there is a similar example in the docs) but this approach seems VERY odd coming from SQL and Pandas.  In particular I don't understand the need to provide a `shape`. The `binby` columns group the data into bins and for each bin I then want to compute the sum. From the docs it seems like this approach was intended for a different use case.  I also found the `groupby` function you mentioned but was never able to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct and this is not the intended use for this approach - so that's why you will have to tune the shape. The `binby` does group the columns into bins, the `shape` sets the number of bins. The default `shape` is 64 if I'm not mistaken. I assumed here that you want a bin for each "business_partner" and "contract_account", which is likely not 64 so that's why I recommended changing the default shape.